# XMonad with GDM on Maverick (Ubuntu 10.10)

Tags: ubuntu, gdm, xmonad, maverick

I'm using xmonad on Ubuntu Maverick (10.10)

First of all I created a new Desktop Entry to make the xmonad session to be accessible from the GDM login screen, but after a reboot GDM doesn't start, and xmonad starts BEFORE gdm, with some strange behaviour (the desktop doesn't change).

Maybe is it a problem with this line of xmonad.hs which I use to open xmobar?

```
   xmobar <- spawnPipe "xmobar"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get [Xmonad](http://genaud.net/2010/05/xmonad-on-lucid-lynx/) up and running with this: